# Converting GLKVector to Objects

Tags: objective-c, colors, glkit

I'm writing a method for a "Color" class that will select a color at random from an array of GLKVector4's (as found in GLKit).  The colors look like this:

```
    self.WHITE=GLKVector4Make(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    self.RED=GLKVector4Make(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    self.GREEN=GLKVector4Make(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    self.BLUE=GLKVector4Make(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    self.BLACK=GLKVector4Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

I want to put them into an array so that I can pick one randomly.  The problem is that GLKVector4's are not NSArray friendly, in the sense that they are not recognized as type id and I can't think of a way to easily convert them.

Is there a way to convert GLKVector's to something I could put into an array? And more importantly, is this a good way to organize colors? Perhaps there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a basic C array?

```
GLKVector4 colors[5] = {self.WHITE, self.RED, self.GREEN, self.BLUE, self.BLACK};
//...
GLKVector4 randomColor = colors[arc4random_uniform(5)];
```